# How do I add the failureSink to elasticsearchSink

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, serilog, serilog-sinks-file, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

I add FileSink as failureSink to ElasticsearchSink from appSettings.json. But "Cannot create instance of type 'Serilog.Core.ILogEventSink' because it is either abstract or an interface." I get an error. How do I fixed it?

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Error",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Error",
            "System": "Error",
            "Quartz": "Error",
            "GraphQL": "Warning",
            "Hateoas": "Warning",
            "MassTransit": "Information"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Elasticsearch",
            "Args": {
                "nodeUris": "http://17.172.25.115:9200",
                "indexFormat": "logstash",
                "templateName": "logstash-template",
                "emitEventFailure":  "WriteToFailureSink, WriteToSelfLog, RaiseCallback",
                "failureSink": {
                    "type": "Serilog.Sinks.File.FileSink, Serilog.Sinks.File",
                    "path": "failures.txt",
                    "fileSizeLimitBytes":  null 
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": "AselsanSatComPAMAStatic"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some mandatory settings in FileSink that we need to configure before the instance of FileSink can be created. You can set something like following and it should work.

```
  "failureSink": {
    "type": "Serilog.Sinks.File.FileSink, Serilog.Sinks.File",
    "path": "failures.txt",
    "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1234567,
    "rollingInterval": "Day",
    "textFormatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"
  }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.